# Url rewrite not working for ajax request to wcf service from http to https

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wcf, url-rewrite-module

```
var strBaseUrl = "http://service.mydomain.com/MyserviceHost/stage/";
    function Login() {
        debugger;
        var LoginInfo = JSON.stringify({ "strAccountName": "#####", "strPassword": "######", "strDeviceId": "################" });
        var strUriGet = strBaseUrl + "OneviewClient.svc/Login";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: strUriGet,
            data: LoginInfo,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            processData: true,
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                debugger;
                //alert("success..." + data);
                console.log("success..." + jqXHR.responseText);
                $("#labelToken").text(data.loginResponse.strToken);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, exception) {
                debugger;
                console.log(xhr.responseJSON);
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Above ajax call is made with http://service.mydomain.com/MyserviceHost/stage/ 
i have written rewrite module wcf service web.config to rewrite all http reuqest to https.
When i am trying to call http link in browser address its simply redirect to https, but in ajax call it wont (it throws network error), is there any things which i missed?

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/MyserviceHost/stage/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

The rule looks correct to me. However I've seen URL Rewrite not working on few instances because of IIS installation issue. To make sure you don't have this issue first check if you can see URL Rewrite icon when you click on site in IIS Manager. You should be able to double click on it and see your above rule without any issue. Just for sanity, I would add very simple rule (for example, redirect xyz.html to abc.html) and see if it works correctly. If you didn't see URL Rewrite Icon but you had installed it in past then you would need to uninstall and reinstall it and re-open IIS Manager.

If above simple test is successful and URL Rewrite is indeed installed then you should use the Chrome Developer Tools to see if AJAX request is getting sent out using correct URL and see the server response.

If you can verify if server is indeed not responding with redirect then your last resort is enable [Failed Request Tracing](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis). This would show if URL Rewrite is being invoked in call chain, if it gets invoked then it would show the input URL it gets and result of regex. This has pointed to root cause in pretty much all cases I've worked with.

Comment: I found from chrome that the first request is sent as Cors Preflight which is aborted as wcf is configured with security mode transport. The actual request after preflight is not being sent.